# Schwarzschild solution question

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry

Since we set the Ricci tensor to be zero everywhere, why is it still a solution if it doesn't apply to the point where the point mass exists? Shouldn't it apply also to that point as well, or am I missing something? Maybe it is just a good aproximation for distances far from the point mass.

Comment: this question should be moved to physics. Anyway, there is no such thing as a point mass in general relativity, in particular not in Schwarzschild solution. If you consider a non-rotating spherical star then the metric above the star coincides with the Swcharzschild (cf. Birkhoff theorem), for the inside look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Hilbert Einstein action for vacuum is proportional to the scalar Ricci and if you vary it using the principle of least action, you get a flat Ricci tensor. Once you couple the gravitational field with physical matter, extra terms will appear. In the Schwarzschild solution, you approximate the physical matter by a single point mass. So the Ricci tensor is zero everywhere except over the point mass.

Comment: I not only agree that it should be moved to physics, but add that a very similar question was already asked there http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113117/gr-matter-free-equations-and-schwarzschild-geometry/113172#113172